# Fetch Candlestick/Kline data from Binance API using Python (preferably requests) to get JSON Dat

Tags: python, json, binance, candlestick-chart

I am developing a telegram bot that fetches Candlestick Data from Binance API. I am unable to get JSON Data as a response. The following code is something that I tried:

```
import requests 
import json
import urllib.request
url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines"
response = requests.request("GET", url)
print(response.text)
```

Desired Output:

```json
[
  [
    1499040000000,      // Open time
    "0.01634790",       // Open
    "0.80000000",       // High
    "0.01575800",       // Low
    "0.01577100",       // Close
    "148976.11427815",  // Volume
    1499644799999,      // Close time
    "2434.19055334",    // Quote asset volume
    308,                // Number of trades
    "1756.87402397",    // Taker buy base asset volume
    "28.46694368",      // Taker buy quote asset volume
    "17928899.62484339" // Ignore
  ]
]
```

Question Edited:

The output that I am getting is:

> {"code":-1102,"msg":"Mandatory parameter 'symbol' was not sent, was empty/null, or malformed."}

Comment: What error / message do you get?

Comment: The output that I am getting is:     `<Response [400]>`

Answer (score 32):

you are missing the mandatory parameters symbol and interval, the query should be like this:

https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=1h

you need to import only requests:

```
import requests

market = 'BTCUSDT'
tick_interval = '1h'

url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol='+market+'&interval='+tick_interval
data = requests.get(url).json()

print(data)
```

Please check the official Binance REST API documentation here: https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md

Comment: Is it possible to pass a list of symbols?

Comment: @HAßdøµ No you can't pass a list of symbols, please refer to the API documentation: https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#klinecandlestick-data.

Comment: @HAßdøµ Via the Exchange-Endpoint of the Binance API, you can get all all symbols that are traded on the Exchange, and then pass them each into your function, e.g. in a for-loop.

Comment: @HalilIbrahimÖzcan That is a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

The requests python package has a `params`, `json` argument, so you don't need to import any of those packages you are importing.

```py
import requests

url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines'
params = {
  'symbol': 'BTCUSDT',
  'interval': '1h'
}
response = requests.get(url, params=params)
print(response.json())
```

Comment: the last line should be: print(response.json()) instead of: print(response.json)

Answer (score 4):

collect data into dataframe from start date to end date

```
import requests
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def gget_binance_data_by_requests(ticker='ETHUSDT', interval='4h', start='2020-01-01 00:00:00', end='2023-07-01 00:00:00'):
  """
  interval: str tick interval - 4h/1h/1d ...
  """
  columns = ['open_time','open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume','close_time', 'qav','num_trades','taker_base_vol','taker_quote_vol', 'ignore']
  usecols=['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'qav','num_trades','taker_base_vol','taker_quote_vol']
  start = int(datetime.datetime.timestamp(pd.to_datetime(start))*1000)
  end_u = int(datetime.datetime.timestamp(pd.to_datetime(end))*1000)
  df = pd.DataFrame()
  print(f'Downloading {interval} {ticker} ohlc-data ...', end=' ')
  while True:
    url = f'https://www.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol={ticker}&interval={interval}&limit=1000&startTime={start}#&endTime={end_u}'
    data = pd.DataFrame(requests.get(url, headers={'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', "Pragma": "no-cache"}).json(), columns=columns, dtype=np.float64)    
    start = int(data.open_time.tolist()[-1])+1
    data.index = [pd.to_datetime(x, unit='ms').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for x in data.open_time]
    data = data[usecols]
    df = pd.concat([df, data], axis=0)
    if end in data.index.tolist():
      break
  print('Done.')
  df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
  df = df.loc[:end]
  return df[['open', 'high', 'low', 'close']]

eth = get_binance_data_by_requests(ticker='ETHUSDT', interval='4h', start='2020-01-01 00:00:00', end='2023-07-01 00:00:00')
eth
```

result:
[image]