# raise JSON DecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: json, binance, binance-api-client

```
    def get_historical_candles(self, symbol, interval):
        data = dict()
        data['symbol'] = symbol
        data['interval'] = interval
        data['limit'] = 1000

        response = requests.get('https://api.binance.com/api/V3/kline', data)

        raw_candles = response.json()

        candles = []

        if raw_candles is not None:
            for c in raw_candles:
                candles.append([c[0], float(c[1]), float(c[2]), float(c[3]), float(c[4]), float(c[5])])

        print(candles)
```

How can i avoid the error mentioned in the title?

I have tried

[Fetch Candlestick/Kline data from Binance API using Python (preferably requests) to get JSON Dat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51358147/fetch-candlestick-kline-data-from-binance-api-using-python-preferably-requests)

and it works well.

However, i need to find out a solution for this approach

```
 response = requests.get('https://api.binance.com/api/V3/kline', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Please read binance API document carefully: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#kline-candlestick-data
2. To debug this error: Obviously it comes from `raw_candles = response.json()`. Therefore, before deserialize the response content, it is a good idea to check the status code and text by `response.status_code` and `response.text`

TL;DR:

An `s` is missing.  The path should be `api/v3/klines`